# paintComponent method doesn't draw anything when I pass class's variable

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

My java code:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ConcentricCircles2D extends JPanel {
double myX = 0;
double myY = 0;
int myWidth = getWidth();
int myHeight = getHeight();

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{

    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);                  
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5.0f)); 
    g2.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(myX, myY, myWidth, myHeight));

}
```

When I use a local variable inside the paintComponent method it works just fine. How can I solve the problem? (I create the panel on separate class.)

Comment: include the code as text in the question and not as an image pls.

Comment: sorry about that, fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myWidth` and `myHeight` values are set only when the `ConcentricCircles2D` object is instantiated. It has zero weight and height at this point.

So this sentence

`Ellipse2D.Double(myX, myY, myWidth, myHeight)`

is equal to

`Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 0, 0)`

and it will paint no ellipse at all.

Replace the sentence

```
 g2.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(myX, myY, myWidth, myHeight));
```

with your original

```
 g2.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()));
```

and an ellipse centered in the parent `JFrame` will be drawn and its dimensions will change if you resize its parent.